# How to simulate NUL character from keyboard?

Tags: character-encoding, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, key

Can we type NUL character (HEX 0) from the keyboard?

Most of the printable character starts from HEX value 20.

Comment: @BrianRoach, i hope you understand the point of my question even if NULL is not a character.

Comment: NULL is a (control) character, in Ascii, Unicode (U+0000), and other standards.

Comment: The character in ASCII corresponding to 0 is *usually* referred to as `NUL`, not `NULL`

Comment: @Brian: NULL isn't a character, but NUL is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh really? What is this I'm seeing in the C89 standard, then:  http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.1.5 (page 108 in this PDF http://read.pudn.com/downloads133/doc/565041/ANSI_ISO%2B9899-1990%2B[1].pdf )? Looks like both are valid in different places, to me. I think NUL is usually a windows-ism.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> works for both Windows and Linux platforms.

Comment: My program says that it is 32, which is same as pressing only space, in my Windows.

Comment: Sublime adds lorem ipsum text on `Ctrl` + `space`  In what context / what application does this sequence work?

Answer (score 5):

See if this control character works:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>

Comment: It is 3 in my operating system: WIndows 10.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>
works on many terminals (worked for me).

Comment: This does work. Curiously Ctrl+` (backtick, tilde key) also sends a null byte.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type <kbd>Num Pad 0</kbd><kbd>Num Pad 0</kbd><kbd>Num Pad 0</kbd> then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>

**Note:** You must use the 0 key on the **numeric key pad** (a regular 0 key won't work for this), and you have to hold down Alt the whole time.  The keystroke isn't emitted until you release the Alt key.

Answer (score -1):

In editing fields in SQL Server, it is Control Zero (Ctrl + 0)