# How to enter NUL character through keyboard

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, nul

How to enter `NUL` character through keyboard. Example, like for for `ESC` character we are using `ctrl+Esc`. For your info: I'm using win 2008 OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate NUL character from keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124786/how-to-simulate-nul-character-from-keyboard)

Comment: But that solution is not working for me.

Comment: Did you try all of the solutions: `CTRL-@`, `CTRL-SPACE`(which is usually an alias for `CTRL-@`) and `CTRL-0`? I didn't down-vote by the way.

Comment: Ya, i tried all those solutions. No Problem, may be people who don't know the answer would h've down voted.