# if someone enter without writing anything then it should terminate

Tags: c, while-loop, null, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    c=getchar();
    while(c!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        c=getchar();
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

We would like to terminate the program by entering NULL character from keyboard but it's not working.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124786/how-to-simulate-nul-character-from-keyboard#9124872

Comment: Note that the usual way to write this code is to read until the end-of-input, not some arbitrary character is reached. To do that you have to fix the type of `c` (it needs to be `int c;`) and change the loop condition: `while (c != EOF)`

Comment: Do you want that if someone enter without writing anything then it should terminate or anything else?

Comment: @GameChanger yes correct, we are looking for the same. how can we terminate in this case.?

Comment: That's not a null character, that's a newline.

Comment: If the user hits enter, that produces a `'\n'` character, not `'\0'`.

Comment: just wanted to understand, is there any way where we can enter null character proactively in c language  ?

Comment: Argh! Why do you keep changing your question? The linked duplicate explained exactly that: A way to enter the NUL character (regardless of language; it has nothing to do with C).

Comment: @melpomene that way doesn't work for me

Comment: @GameChanger What terminal are you using? E.g. I can't find a way that works on the Windows 7 console, but there are no issues on Linux.

Comment: I am using windows 10, and I also can't find a way that can help me to enter null character.

Comment: Don't enter a *nul-character* as the sentinel for end of string. Normal people don't write `string + nul-char` as input. Most enter `string` and expect the program to take that as input. That why `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` is the norm for *character-oriented* input. For *line-oriented* input, `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline`) are the norm. For *formatted-input*, then `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` (or in some cases, simply `fscanf()` is warranted). Choose the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

As commented before, entering the '\0' character from terminal can be done by:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>

The associated c code may be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c;

  do
  {
    c = getchar();
    if ((c == EOF) || (c == '\0'))
    {
      break;
    }
    printf("%c", c);
  } while (c != '\n');

  return 0;
}
```